# xrdp no soundcards found

Tags: 18.04, xrdp

I did a minimal install of Ubuntu 18.04 on a laptop. I wanted to put the computer in my attic, so I setup xrdp. I can connect to the laptop from my Windows computer and most things are working as expected. The problem is, the sound card is not recognized by the remote session.

If I login using the laptop keyboard/display, I can list sound cards with this command:

```
aplay -l
```

BUT, if I login with xrdp, and give the same command, I get this:

```
aplay -l
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

BUT, BUT, if I login with xrdp, and give this command, it works:

```
sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20590 Analog [CX20590 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

So how can I get my sound card recognized by the remote session?

Thanks,
Jake

Comment: Have you installed xrdp-pulseaudio-installer and run xrdp-build-pulse-modules?

Comment: I installed xrdp-pulseaudio-installer and built the rdp_source and rdp_sink modules. I can see xrdp sink and xrdp source in Pulse Volume Control.

Comment: Do you have another user logged in in that machine? Pulse audio normally can only serve one user.

Comment: No other users.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by adding my username to the the "audio" group. This isn't required if you login at the console, but it is required if you login via xrdp or ssh.