# How to enable sound on remote machine with xrdp server?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones, camera, xrdp

I have this setup:

1. Main computer (Ubuntu 20)

   - monitor
   - mouse
   - keyboard
2. Remote computer (Ubuntu 20)

   - xrdp server
   - internet camera
   - headphones with microphone

Everything is lying on one desk, I want to control two computers with one keyboard, mouse and monitor.

When I log in to my "remote computer" normally everything is working (camera, headphones) but when i log in through xdrp connection my camera and headphones are not detected.

What I need to do to be able to use my camera and headphones when i'm logged in as remote user?

// update
When I'm logged in as remote user, computer is not detecting any sound cards:

```
aplay -l
aplay: device list:276: no soundcards found...
```

Comment: Ok, I found answer at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058779/xrdp-no-soundcards-found